# ASPNET Core Server Sent Events / Response flush

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

While there is no official documentation, does anyone know how SSE may be implemented using ASP.NET Core?

I suspect one implementation may use custom middleware, but maybe it is possible to do that in controller action?

Comment: Are you speaking of SignalR?

Comment: No, there is no SignalR for Core yet.

Comment: As a matter of fact, SignalR 3 is available in rc1-final on both the official nuget feed as well as on the myget stables https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetmaster and nightlies. That's why I asked. However, it won't be ready for release, when ASP.NET Core 1.0 is released as mentioned on the roadmap https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that. I will take a look at the source, maybe I will find something useful. At this situation, complete framework is a little bit overkill. I have a single uni-directional channel, implemented using websockets and I am searching for ways how to make it even simpler.

Comment: pre Core: https://github.com/erizet/ServerSentEvent4Net

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Client Side - wwwroot/index.html

On page load, create an `EventSource` for the `http://www.somehost.ca/sse` url. Then write its events to the console.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var source = new EventSource('sse');

        source.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
        };

        source.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('onopen');
        };

        source.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log('onerror');
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

### Server Side Alternative #1 - Use Middleware

The middleware handles the `sse` path. It sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/event-stream`, which the server socket event requires. It writes to the response stream, without closing the connection. It mimics doing work, by delaying for five seconds between writes.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/sse"))
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

        for(var i = 0; true; ++i)
        {
            // WriteAsync requires `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`
            await response
                .WriteAsync($"data: Middleware {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");

            await response.Body.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        }
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

### Server Side Alternative #2 - Use a Controller

The controller does the exact same thing as the middleware does.

```
[Route("/api/sse")]
public class ServerSentEventController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        var response = Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

        for(var i = 0; true; ++i)
        {
            await response
                .WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");

            response.Body.Flush();
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

### Client Side Console Output in Firefox

This is the result in the Firefox console window. Every five seconds a new messages arrives.

```
onopen
onmessage: Message 0 at 4/15/2016 3:39:04 PM
onmessage: Message 1 at 4/15/2016 3:39:09 PM
onmessage: Message 2 at 4/15/2016 3:39:14 PM
onmessage: Message 3 at 4/15/2016 3:39:19 PM
onmessage: Message 4 at 4/15/2016 3:39:24 PM
```

References:

- [The above sample on GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetCoreServerSentEvents)
- [The HTML Living Standard, section 9.2 Server-sent events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#server-sent-events)
- [Http Push Technology on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)
- [Chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Thank you Shaun, your answer looks very comprehensive. I will transfer reputation points soon, I am still having problems reproducing this on RC1 on local machine and Azure. It looks like the response is not flushed on each iteration. Maybe it a good time to move to pre-RC2.

Comment: @Zygimantas It's definitely a good time to move to pre-RC2. I haven't tried the above on RC1. While working with pre-RC2 can be painful, you will learn a massive amount as you work thru the pain.

Comment: thank you for pushing to the bleeding edge :) Now I can confirm that is works on pre-RC2 as expected, but not on RC1.

Comment: @Zygimantas Good stuff. The RC1 stuff is good and is a "go live" product. The RC2 though is the future, so it is a good idea to start learning it. I am glad to hear that this works for you. :)

Comment: I have also noticed you are using IHttpContextAccessor instead of inheriting ControllerBase and calling this.HttpContext. I haven't seen this before on RC1. Are there any advantages of doing that?

Comment: @Zygimantas I am not sure about the advantages of the one over the other. I do know that the new MVC supports plain-old-crl-object (POCO) controllers. In other words, these are controllers that do not inherit from the `Controller` class. I tend away from inheritance for simple projects to avoid the overhead. There are benefits to inheriting the `Controller` class. It comes with a lot of helper methods, so to speak. Here is the class. Checkout its public/protect members to see what it gives you: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs

Comment: To see the WriteAsyn() on Response you need to include using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Is there a way to send message to only specific users? Can we utilize_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User for this?

Comment: @RadenkoZec I'm afraid I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: How do you know when to close the connection? When I refresh the browser it makes a second request which calls the controller again leaving 2 loops running.

Comment: You can close the connection from the client side by calling eventSource.close().

Comment: Does anyone know why the response to this request is always text/html and not text/event-stream?  I continually get "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection." in Chrome, though it doesn't seem to abort or reconnect at all.  Odd.

Comment: Nevermind, I found this is an artifact of HotModuleReplacement of the webpack middleware stuff.

Comment: @Zygimantas did you get this working on Azure? It works on my machine, but on Azure the response never completes.

Comment: @mcintyre321yes, but later I have moved to websockets because latency of sending data to the server over separate rest api was too big.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin is this solution good for sending big files from server to client?

Answer (score 25):

Server sent events can be implemented entirely in a controller action.

This is based on the answer by Shaun Luttin, but it's more of a real-world example in that it will hold open the connection indefinitely, and it sends messages to the `EventSource` in response to messages being created.

```
using Example.Models;
using Example.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Example.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SseMessagesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMessageRepository messageRepository;
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings;

        public SseMessagesController(IMessageRepository messageRepository)
        {
            this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
            this.jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task GetMessages(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

            EventHandler<MessageCreatedArgs> onMessageCreated = async (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var message = eventArgs.Message;
                    var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, jsonSettings);
                    await Response.WriteAsync($"data:{messageJson}\n\n");
                    await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // TODO: log error
                }
            };
            messageRepository.MessageCreated += onMessageCreated;

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            messageRepository.MessageCreated -= onMessageCreated;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the `EventSource` connects to `/api/ssemessages`, we add an event delegate to the `MessageCreated` event on the message repository. Then we check every 1 second to see if the `EventSource` has been closed, which will cause the request to be cancelled. Once the request is cancelled, we remove the event delegate.

The event delegate gets the `Message` object from the event arguments, serializes it to JSON (using camel case to be consistent with ASP.NET Core's default behavior when returning an object result), writes the JSON to the body, and flushes the body's stream to push the data to the `EventSource`.

For more on creating the event delegate, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern) and [this update for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/modern-events).

Also, if you host this behind Nginx, you'll want to read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673298/12275896) and [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/801629).

Comment: Hey delial, thanks for the answer! Not sure if you knew, but this question is more than 3 years old - if you'd like to focus your efforts on new questions, you can use the "Newest" tab to achieve that. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?tab=Newest) is the link to newest C# questions.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo or gist with a complete example including a `IMessageRepository` implementation?

Comment: @MarkG I know it's 1 year later, but probably this would be helpful: https://github.com/Nordes/Sample.SSEvent (I don't think I will erase it, but it can help to see where events are coming from and how to broadcast).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! using "cancellationToken" and "response.body.FlushAsync" was essential for my project.