# Stream proxy a live stream in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, video-streaming

I have a stream url of my webcam, that returns a content-type of "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary", let say that it is accessible via http://mywebcam/livrestream.cgi

I would like to create a proxy in ASP.NET CORE that can return the same stream.

I've created a route that get the stream :

```
[Route("api/test")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Test()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var inputStream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://mywebcam/livrestream.cgi");
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
    {
        // what to do ?
    }, "video/mp4");
    return response;
}
```

It seems that I have to use PushStreamContent. But what should I do ? 
An endless while loop that query regulary the stream ? something else ?

Comment: Why using `HttpResponseMessage`? That is no longer used in asp.net-core. Secondly, also take headers into consideration to allow for the parts/chunks (ie: range headers)

Comment: why not, but i don't know what I should do in PushStreamContent ? or there is another way to accomplish that ?

Comment: see my solution for similar question about `PushStreamContent` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781314/4983201

Answer (score 7):

`HttpResponseMessage` is no longer used as a first class citizen in asp.net-core framework and will be serialized as a normal object model.

Asp.net Core has built-in support for range requests.

Retrieve the stream from your accessible link and pass the stream on including the appropriate content type.

```
static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>();
const string WebCamUrl = "http://mywebcam/livrestream.cgi";

[Route("api/test")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test() {        
    var contentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary";
    Stream stream = await client.Value.GetStreamAsync(WebCamUrl);
    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType) {
         EnableRangeProcessing = true
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's working, the video doesn't launch in a dashjs player :

Comment: <div class="code">
        <video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="http://localhost:52867/api/test" controls="true"></video>
    </div>

Comment: in the network inspector, I can see the request is "pending"

Comment: and finaly, i have net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Tim have you tried debugging the test endpoint to see where the error is thrown?

Comment: @Tim might also need to pass the range headers from the client on to the cgi end point.

Comment: if I copy/paste the http://mywebcam/livrestream.cgi url in chrome, the video of my webcam is correctly streaming ; but maybe chrome is doing something more

Comment: @Tim check updated code. The code needs to act like the browser. Curious though. Is the cgi return a raw feed or a document?

Comment: @Tim I would also suggest stepping through the code in debug mode to narrow down where the error is happening.

Comment: When I put the webcam stream in chrome, I have theses headers :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 06:35:35 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
;
the type is "document"
;
and now, with headers range, it's stuck on the SendAsync request. (note I had to convert from System.Net.Http.RangeHeaderValue and microsoft.net.http.RangeHeaderValue

Comment: thanks to have taken the time to answer me, I will give up, I think there's to many things I don't understand. I'll give ou the bounty reward